# Image conversion svg in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, svg

I have an application on rails and there I generate svg images to return to the user by email, but I want return this in another format (png or jpg). Does anyone have any tips on how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mini_magick gem to convert svg to other formats. You will need to install librsvg before installing ImageMagick for it to work properly.

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(svg_filename)
image.format 'png'
image.write 'output.png'
```